# map and reduce an array

Tags: arrays, scala, scala-collections

I want to map an array in every 3 elements, output is many [k,v]pairs, for example:

```
input: array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,7,12,11)   
output: (1 => 2,3) (4 => 5,6)(7 => 8,9) (7 => 12,11)
```

And I also want to reduce these pairs by keys, for example ,if I want to collect the data with key=7, then the output will be `(7=> 8,9,12,11).`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sounds like a good place to just simply iterate for every pair of three (`i += 3`), and use a multimap to add values. Typically in a key/value store, you wouldn't have duplicate key values anyhow

Comment: Did you have a question for us?  "I want" is not a question.

Comment: How is this question related to Apache Spark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need is following

```
val input = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7, 12, 11)
val output = input.toSeq.grouped(3)
  .map(g => (g.head, g.tail)).toList
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .mapValues(l => l.flatMap(_._2))
```

Result would be

> Map(4 -> List(5, 6), 7 -> List(8, 9, 12, 11), 1 -> List(2, 3))

Comment: Good one with groupped()

Comment: Hello, I've got another problem, if the input Array is a partition of RDD , which means I need to create [k,v] pairs inside a partition, it that ok?

Comment: @miaoiao, I'm not sure what you are trying to do but with RDD it would be really hard to achieve. RDD is as "Resilient **Distributed** Dataset" which means by default there is no guarantees on ordering and even on splitting between nodes (example: you might have 6-elements RDD that is split 4:2 between two Spark-nodes and your operation makes no sense after such split). You probably should aggregate data on some previous step instead of dumping it into a uniform list and trying to group it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 res0 = list.grouped(3).map {x => (x(0), List(x(1),x(2)))}.toList
 // you must dump your converted data format into your storage eg hdfs. 
 // And not the entire thing in the form of array. Transform in form of 
 // (key,value) and dump in hdfs. That will save a lot of computation.

 res1 = sc.parallelize(res0)
 res2 = res1.reduceByKey(_++_).collect
```

But I am not sure how much scalable this solution would be.

**EDIT**

```
val res1 = sc.parallelize(arr)
// (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,7,12,11) 
val res2 = res1.zipWithIndex.map(x._2/3,List(x._1))
//  (1,0),(2,1),...(12,10),(11,11) -> (0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6)
val res3 = res2.reduceByKey(_++_).map(_._2)
//(0,List(1,2,3)),(1,List(4,5,6)) -> List(1,2,3),List(4,5,6)
val res4 = res3.map(x => x match {
   case x1::xs => (x1,xs)
}).reduceByKey(_++_)

//List(1,2,3) - > (1,List(2,3)) -> reduceByKey
//(1,List(2,3)),(4,List(5,6)),(7,List(8,9,12,11))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hello, I've got another problem, if the input Array is a partition of RDD , which means I need to create [k,v] pairs inside a partition, it that ok?

Comment: Thats what I have said in the answer, to preprocess array to [K,V] before .